# How I can connect instance methods to my object

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

**Hello guys!**

Wrote code that generate player for me:

```
class PlayerPlane: SKSpriteNode {


    static func populatePlayerPlane() -> SKSpriteNode {
        let playerPlane = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "airplane_1_14")
        playerPlane.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
        playerPlane.zPosition = 50
        return playerPlane
    }

    func fireEnemies() {
        print("Attack")
    }
}
```

As it was generated with `SKSpriteNode` I can't attach method fireEnemies. And now I can't cast it down from `SKSpriteNode` to `PlayerPlane`.

Sure I can make everything other way using `PlayerPlane` initialisers but may be I miss something and there are other smarter solutions for attaching method **fireEmenies** to instances of **PlayerPlane**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a `PlayerPlane` as a class then you can make it this way (as `PlayerPlane` is a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` you can use it's initializers):

```
class PlayerPlane: SKSpriteNode {

    static func populatePlayerPlane() -> PlayerPlane {
        let playerPlane = PlayerPlane(imageNamed: "airplane_1_14")
        playerPlane.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
        playerPlane.zPosition = 50
        return playerPlane
    }

    func fireEnemies() {
        print("Attack")
    }
}
```

But you can also use a protocol and write an extension for `SKSpriteNode` which is convenient if you want to make other objects/structs adopt `PlayerPlane` functionality:

```
protocol PlayerPlane {

    func fireEnemies()
}

extension SKSpriteNode : PlayerPlane {

    func fireEnemies() {
        print("Attack")
    }

}

extension SKSpriteNode {

    static func populatePlayerPlane() -> SKSpriteNode {
        let playerPlane = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "airplane_1_14")
        playerPlane.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
        playerPlane.zPosition = 50
        return playerPlane
    }

}
```

Finally, when you want "other" way to attach `fireEnemies` functionality to your `PlayerPlane` you can also write an extension for a protocol:

```
class PlayerPlane: SKSpriteNode {

    static func populatePlayerPlane() -> PlayerPlane {
        let playerPlane = PlayerPlane(imageNamed: "airplane_1_14")
        playerPlane.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
        playerPlane.zPosition = 50
        return playerPlane
    }
}


protocol FireEnemies {
    func fireEnemies()
}

extension PlayerPlane : FireEnemies {
    func fireEnemies() {
        print("Attack")
    }
}
```